# Migration Azure Mobile Services to Azure Mobile App: UserId has changed

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm facing an interesting challenge as I'm setting up a brand new instance of an Azure Mobile App connected to an existing DB of an existing Azure Mobile Services running in production.

The app running in production with AMS has Microsoft Account authentication and we filter user'data server-side using the `context.userid` field. This field looks like `MicrosoftAccount:abcdef...`.

After setting up a new Azure Mobile App with Microsoft authentication support, I'm getting a userId that is different, something like sid:ABC...

Using the documentation, I was able to get more details about user identity using the `getIdentity()` api:

`context.user.getIdentity().then((data) => { });`

But I'm still unable to find the "old" UserId that was used in the AMS world... and therefore I cannot have link between the existing data and the new app.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if `context.userid` exactly means the email address. 
However, you can get the account email of the logged in user with the following.

```
context.user.getIdentity().then(function (userInfo) {
    var userId = userInfo.aad.claims.emailaddress;
});
```

Comment: The problem is that in the existing DB (for the production) I don't have the email address for the user. I only have the userId that was available with the Azure Mobile Services...

Comment: @jalfp, As the userid should be provided by each IDP, the `sid` is session id provided by Azure Mobile  App. You can sign in https://<your_app_name>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me to find whether the user id you used in your DB existed in the `user_claims` section. And then you can try to find your userid in `context.user` object as which has contains it according to the source code: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/blob/master/src/auth/user.js#L24

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT I tried this exact approach, but I don't find in the appropriate id :-( The id I have in the DB looks like this: MicrosoftAccount:edb421b011b7955b07c8bfd73c77a8dc while what I see in the claims/user object looks like this { "typ":"urn:microsoftaccount:id","val":"ca5037e782461b00" }

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT the only solution I can think about is updating the app and push the new MS account ID I get after logging in with LiveSDK in the Azure Mobile Services. The only problem is that if people doesn't sync with this particular update I will have no way to retrieve their content after the migration. Any other suggestions ? Thanks,

Comment: @japf, you are right, and we suggest you to use the user's email address as the userid, as the register email is the invariant value.

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT the problem is that the app is alredy live in production ! And I don't have the user's email for the 10 000 users that are currently using the app...